# Find Nearby GPS Navigation Route

Tags: c#, dictionary, navigation, gps, sqlgeography

I am developing a car pooling website. For that, I have created the database which has the different route options selected by different user. These routes are saved in the Database as Geography datatype. For data access, I used Entity Framework. In the C# code, I used DBGeography datatype for process the routes.

I have a requirement that, the user can select one route, and identify the users who selected the same/nearby route which is saved in the database. How do I achieve this?

Comment: How do you define nearby routes ? How are the routes encoded (i.e. start and finsih point or as a set of coordinates ?)
In fac I amnot totally sure where your question is, do you have trouble finding what routes are similar ?

Comment: I'd ask the folks at [Geographic Information Systems SE](http://gis.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [STDistance](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933808.aspx) function in SQL to determine the distance between the Geography's or [DbGeography.Distance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.spatial.dbgeography.distance%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) if you are working in EF (example [here](http://kindohm.com/blog/2013/04/24/sql-spatial-search-demo.html)).